# Python - insert into list horizontally in table

Tags: python, list, stack

i'm not particularly sure how to explain this, but this is the output I am currently getting:

```
0x0 PUSH1       80       ['80']
0x2 PUSH1       40       ['40']
0x4 MSTORE               []
0x8 PUSH2       0010     ['0010']
```

for each time a  PUSH item occurs, I would like to insert the last item into the list horizontally so I get this representation of the stack:

```
0x0 PUSH1       80       ['80']
0x2 PUSH1       40       ['40', '80']
0x4 MSTORE               
0x8 PUSH2       0010     ['0010', '40', '80']
```

this is my current code:

```
for (addr, op, params), y in zip(self.instructions, self.stack[::-1]):     
        codes = []
        for x in range(0, 33):
            if op == 'PUSH' + str(x):
                codes.append(params)
        print addr + "\t" + op + "\t\t" + params + "\t" + str(codes)
```

I'm sorry if this is unclear, been stuck on this for hours, thank you for the help!

Comment: Does the push go to the front or the end? You started with 80, then pushed 40 to get 40, 80. Then pushed 001, and got 40, 80, 0010 rtaher than 0010, 40, 80 (APart from that, what's going wrong with your solution?)

Comment: my bad, let me correct it!

Comment: What do you mean by horizontally?

Comment: So - is what's going wrong that you get 80, 40, 0010 rtaher than the reverse order?

Comment: no, im not getting that at all, my current output is the first set of data, I would like the second example as my output

Comment: Can you tell me what's in `stack` and `instructions`? (Your code looks like it might sorta work, but the problem might be there or where you zip, depending on what that looks like).

Comment: Also, why `for x in range(0, 33)`?

Comment: because in my full code the PUSH items can range from PUSH1 to PUSH32 - don't worry, its solved now, but thank you anyways!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is on the second line of the code you posted. You are doing `codes = []` every iteration of the loop which is erasing the contents of the codes list. Try moving that above the `for` loop so it doesn't keep getting erased.

In addition, your implementation seems very inefficient since you don't need to actually loop 33 times to check the code, you can just use comparisons. First, get the number at the end of the operation by doing `number = int(op[-1])`, then you can just check `if (op[0:-1] == 'PUSH') and (0 <= number < 33): ...`

Comment: Thank you so much! This has been bugging me for hours haha!

Comment: No problem! I also just edited my post to give you some more feedback that will make your code much more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems in this code as I see.

1.
`codes = []` in the Line 2 assigns an empty `list` to `codes`, which is why you are always ending up with a single value in `codes`.

2.
To insert `params` to the front of the list use,`codes = params + codes` OR `codes.insert(0,params)` OR `codes[:0] = [params]`

Answer (score 1):

I think initializing "codes" inside the FOR loop is causing the issue. Moreover append function on a list adds the element at the last and if you want to add the element in the first position then you might want to use insert with position argument. You may try the following.

```
codes = []
for (addr, op, params), y in zip(self.instructions, self.stack[::-1]):     
        for x in range(0, 33):
            if op == 'PUSH' + str(x):
                codes.insert(0, params)
                new_codes = codes
            else:
                new_codes = []
        print addr + "\t" + op + "\t\t" + params + "\t" + str(new_codes)
```